# What is the product obtained when methyl vinyl ketone is reacted with 1,2-ethanedithiol and the product is further hydrogenated with Raney Nickel?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I was solving questions from aldehyde, ketones and ethers and I came across a question that asks:

> [image]
>
> What is the product obtained when Methyl vinyl ketone is reacted with 1,2-Ethanedithiol and the product is further hydrogenated with Raney Nickel?

**My thoughts:**

[image]

I thought that the reaction could be similar to the one where we react a ketone with ethylene glycol, then on further hydrogenation the double bond breaks. I may be wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Also, do note that it is Raney nickel, not "Rancy" nickel.

Answer (score 4):

The answer could be 3 or 4.

1,2-ethanedithiol will react with the carbonyl group to form a dithiane (similar to the ethylene glycol reaction). Reaction of this with Raney Nickel/H2 desulfurises it, so the whole process is effectively a reduction of the carbonyl group to CH2. It depends on the reaction conditions whether the double bond survives. Raney Nickel can reduce alkenes.

You can read more about it here [1](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/protectivegroups/carbonyl/1,3-dithiolanes.htm) and here [2](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2011/09/30/reagent-friday-raney-nickel/)

Comment: In the presence of Ni(R)/H2 I would expect desulfurization  and double bond reduction, i.e., n-butane. In the presence of degassed Ni(R), the double bond may survive. However, because the desulfurization is likely radical in nature, 2-butenes in addition to 1-butene would be expected. Your thoughts?

Comment: I have modified my answer. Just stirring in EtOH with Raney Ni can desulfurize some of these. I think this is a poor example to teach this reaction  with as there are these other possibilities . I suspect this was set without thinking too hard about it, or reference to the literature.

Comment: I agree. This type of question does a disservice to the facts.